# Are absolute paths in a CGI script secure?

Tags: security, path, cgi, absolute

I'm creating a new design for a website, and there is an old CGI script, which sends an email to our server.
I can't post the code here because of privacy issues, but the problem will be clear in a second.

This CGI script takes some templates, and then redirects to a "thanks.htm" page. But while doing this, it is using absolute paths.

Now the question: Is it secure to use absolute paths? I mean, is it possible to read out the CGI scripts to get information about the server architecture?

Thanks in advance,
Greetings Thunderhook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which platform or webserver, but regardless, A properly configured web server shouldn't be able to serve readable cgi scripts.  I would think that in a secured environment, the cgi-bin directory should live outside of accessible webspace.

IMHO, the problem with using absolute paths isn't a security issue as much as an extensibility issue.  If it were my app, I would set an OS environment variable to the document root, then build the absolute path using that variable.  Does that provide some added security?  Maybe -  as your concerns about file structure recon are somewhat mitigated.  But it certainly makes it easier to reconfigure the app, or port it to a new server/location.

Comment: Just as I thought, thank you for your information. The idea about the environment variable sounds good, I think I'll change that!